# Exercise task with main memory

Tags: memory-management, transactions

The Exercise is

> Computer A has a main memory of size HA 2 MiB, and computer B has a main memory of HB = 256 MiB. Both computers process single transactions that have a size of s=84 KiB. Each of the computers loads a maximum number of transactions into the main memory so that at least 512 KiB are still reserved for the processing algorithm. After that, all transactions in the main memory are processed as a batch. The time to load a transaction is 2 ms in both systems. Computer A processes a transaction in 4 ms, computer B needs 7 ms to process a transaction.
>
> Which of the two systems is faster with the processing of all transactions finished? Is there a number of transactions that are processed equally fast by both systems? Justify your answers and give the complete calculation path to your answer.

I need to know if my answer is correct, and if not, *why*.
My answer would be:

Computer A has 2048 KiB - 512 KiB = 1536 KiB
1536 KiB / 84 KiB = 18 transactions
18 transactions * 4 ms = 72 ms

Computer B has 262144 KiB - 512 KiB = 261632 KiB
261632 KiB / 84 KiB = 3114 transactions
3114 transactions * 7 ms = 21798 ms

Computer B takes longer to process than computer A.

Now one question I have is that I'm pretty sure that this is not the right answer to this exercise, because the 2 ms, for loading the transaction, are not included in my answer.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: The answer would seem to depend on the possibility to load and process transactions concurrently. And with *finished* explicated as *processing of all transactions finished*, it would help to similarly have a start like *begin loading of first transaction*.

Comment: Well, let's assume there is no possibility to load and process more than 1 transaction at the same time. How would my solution change?

Comment: *If* time from *start loading to finish processing* was sought, almost not at all: processing takes longer than loading, time would increase by the time to load *one* single transaction. (The exercise speaks of multiple answers because it asks more than one question.)

Comment: Thank you very much, this really helps a lot. And what about the other questions? Would you have a suggestion for a solution?

Comment: Please credit the original source of all copied material.

Comment: The exercise was published by our university in an online portal. How should I cite this source?